# “Curdle me sour”

Tags: expressions, idioms

I am reading a children’s book called gerinimo Stilton, the curse of the cheese pyramid. 
I found an expression “curdle me sour” in the book. 
I thought it was an idom so looked it up. I got nothing from the internet.

The protagonist is a mouse in trouble when he said this. 
If this a fictitious expression as in the world of the mouse, 
I guess  there can be a relevant one from which the author referred in real life. But all I can think of is “oh my god” 
Since I couldn’t find the answer on the internet, 
I decided to ask experts here.

[image: enter image description (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JmKj.jpg)![enter image description here]

Comment: I don't think the expression will catch on (outside of the cheese community, that is).

Comment: It was probably invented by analogy with phrases like "[colour me confused](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15188/what-is-the-origin-of-color-me-confused)" or "[shiver me timbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiver_my_timbers)"

Comment: Consider that "curdle" is what happens to milk when it's turned to cheese.

Comment: The only non-Geronimo Stilton book in which a Google Books search finds a match for "curdle me sour" is [_The Fall of the Dagger_](https://books.google.com/books?id=9SVRCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT304&dq=%22curdle+me+sour%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVraDq-ZPbAhVD6Z8KHSfcD-4Q6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22curdle%20me%20sour%22&f=false) a 2016 novel by Glenda Larke: "_Curdle me sour, the royal whelp is going to be a fobbing remarkable monarch. Who would have thought it?_" Not much of a groundswell.

Comment: It would probably be a more common idiom if there were more English-speaking cheeses around.

Comment: Google Ngrams is missing the "Cheesian English" corpus.